# Ubuntu suddenly at 1024x768 resolution and 'unknown monitor' after reboot

Tags: ubuntu, multiple-monitors, resolution

Did a reboot after changing my computer's hostname, and suddenly only one of my monitors gets an image - and is now stuck at 1024x768 resolution, with display settings saying 'unknown monitor'.

Before reboot I had 4 monitors working with max resolutions and correctly identified, the primary one a widescreen running 3440x1440.

I have no idea what caused this. Before reboot I remember doing 2 things that "changed things":

1. Struggled with trying to install Steam (client refused to start after installing through Ubuntu Software). Ended up doing `sudo apt purge steam` and `sudo apt autoclean && sudo apt autoremove` a couple of times.
2. (unrelated to 1) Changed computer hostname (edited /etc/hostname and /etc/hosts)

Anyone have an idea what may have caused this, and how I can fix it?

Answer (score 2):

Got it! All I needed to do was run `sudo ubuntu-drivers autoinstall` and reboot.

Thanks to [Pilot6 over at Ask Ubuntu for the solution](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1237590/not-able-to-change-the-nvidia-driver-in-ubuntu-20-04).